# Como que faço para que o calendário comece na segunda?

Tags: php, html5

```
     <?php
        function linha($semana){
            echo "<tr>";

            for ($i=0; $i<=6; $i++):
                if(isset($semana[$i])):
                    echo "<td>$semana[$i]</td>";
                else:
                    echo "<td> </td>";
                endif;

            endfor;

            echo "</tr>";
        }



        function calendario(){
            $dia = 1;
            $semana = array();
            while ($dia <= 31):
                array_push($semana,$dia);

                if(count($semana)== 7) :
                    linha($semana);
                    $semana = array();
                endif;

            $dia++;

            endwhile;

            linha($semana);

        }
     ?>
      <table border="1">
            <tr>
                 <th>Dom</th>
                 <th>Seg</th>
                 <th>Ter</th>
                 <th>Qua</th>
                 <th>Quin</th>
                 <th>Sex</th>
                 <th>Sáb</th>
            </tr>
           <?php calendario() ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: Você espera até segunda e começa a usar ele, não vai ter erro. brincadeira. detalha mais seu problema.

Comment: kkkk, tipo meu dia 1 só começa domingo, e quero mudar para que o Dia 1 seja outro dia da semana sem ser o domingo...

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue pegar o primeiro dia da semana com `date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y")."W".date("W")));` (Não se esqueça de definir o `date_default_timezone_set()`).